# How change fb dialog title in iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, dialog, facebook-ios-sdk, apprequests

how can I change title in dialog "send requests" ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the title parameter in presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession method.

```
 [FBWebDialogs
     presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
     message:msg
     title:@"Change your title here"
     parameters:nil
     handler:nil
 ];
```

Comment: yep, but only in Facebook 3.2 SDK :)

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: i used 3.1., now i use 3.2 and i can change title. In version 3.1  this function is disabled.